# Runtime Error 5 : Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Macro for making a Pivot Table in Sheet "Pivot" from Data Sheet "Sheet1".

Although I am able to run the macro in my system but in other systems, it gives a Runtime Error 5 at `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create` line.

```
Sub Make_Pivot()
'
' Make_Pivot Macro

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("D:G").Select
Range("G1").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C4:R1048576C7", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6

Sheets("Pivot").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NDL")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Tracking IDs"), "Count of Tracking IDs", xlCount

Columns("A:B").Select
Range("B1").Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("G13").Select
Sheets("Count").Select
Range("A1").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("F18").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the dynamic code below (explanations inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Make_Pivot()

' Make_Pivot Macro

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache
Dim SrcData As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

' set the workbook object
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

' set the worksheet object where the Pivot-Table will be
Set PvtSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")

' set the worksheet object where the Data lies
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- last row in column "G"
    ' set the Pivot-Cache SourceData object
    Set SrcData = .Range("D1:G" & LastRow)
End With

' Create the Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = WB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                SourceData:=SrcData.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
' === FOR DEBUG ONLY ===
MsgBox PvtCache.SourceData

' Set the Pivot Table Object (already created in previous macro run)
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' <-- pivot table still doesn't exist >> need to create it
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Pivot" sheet, start from Cell A1
    Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("NDL")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Tracking IDs"), "Count of Tracking IDs", xlCount
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot table, with updated Pivot Cache
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

' rest of your code goes here ...

End Sub
```

***Note***: There's no need to use so many `Select` and `Selection`, instead use fully qualifed `Range`, `Worksheet` and `Object`s.

Comment: It is giving me Runtime Error 91 at line " SrcData = .Range("D1:J" & LastRow)"

Comment: @Agrinthus what is the value of `LastRow` when you run it ?

Comment: My Columns A,B, C are empty and Data is there in Column D-G till row 17. (I edited your code's J to G while running)

Comment: The issue persists at the same line

Comment: @Agrinthus what value are you getting for `LastRow` ?  Did you copy my entire code ? or just bits and pieces ?

Comment: Copied your entire code. How do I know the value of `LastRow` ?

Comment: @Agrinthus you run in debug mode, and you step with your cursor on it (you will get it's value)

Comment: Okay. It gives 1003. And `SrcData` gives Nothing

Comment: @Agrinthus `SrcData` is a `Range`, so it's set to the Range in `"Sheet1".Range("D1:G1003")`.  you are stil gtting an error there ?

Comment: @Agrinthus my bad, try now the edited code, forget to `Set` the `Range`

Comment: Cool. That error is gone but got a new Runtime error at `Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")`

Comment: @Agrinthus try my edited code, see what are you getting in the messagebox

Comment: I think there is no `Set` for `PvtSheet` too. Right ?

Comment: @Agrinthus YEP +1, try now

Comment: Awesome. Works now. Thanks !